# Getting hidden inputs fields and can't even get the page source with selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get page source. so, i can make query with post requests and retrieve data from result. but, initially i don't even get page source.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser=webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('url.aspx')

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)


print soup.prettify()
```

i am getting following page source:

```
...
</script>
  <noscript>
   Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.
  </noscript>
 </head>
 <body onload="challenge()">
  <form action="/corpweb/CorpSearch/CorpSearch.aspx" method="POST">
   <input name="TS019ab495_id" type="hidden" value="3"/>
   <input name="TS019ab495_cr" type="hidden" 
value="c4fb95a11ceaf83e82fc10400957ab7c:yvyz:a9qeoPYm:1996871542"/>
   <input name="TS019ab495_76" type="hidden" value="0"/>
   <input name="TS019ab495_md" type="hidden" value="1"/>
   <input name="TS019ab495_rf" type="hidden" value="0"/>
   <input name="TS019ab495_ct" type="hidden" value="0"/>
   <input name="TS019ab495_pd" type="hidden" value="0"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it's showing the fields?

Comment: @e4c5 sorry i can't you .

Comment: <input name="TS019ab495_76" type="hidden" value="0"/>

Comment: @e4c5 i get the same result if i use http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/CorpWeb/CorpSearch/CorpSummary.aspx?FEIN=463459666&SEARCH_TYPE=1 this link(this is query result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0")
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
broswer = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
broswer.get('http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/corpweb/CorpSearch/CorpSearch.aspx')
time.sleep(5)

print(broswer.page_source)
```

try this, hope it will solve the javascript problem

Comment: i am on mac, what should i write instead of ~linux x86_64~  in .set_preference?

Comment: keep it, it wont matter

Comment: i getting this error now: ` soup=BeautifulSoup(profile.page_source)
AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'page_source'` @Exprator

Comment: change soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.text) from soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

Comment: now i m getting this buddy: `soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.text) 
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined` @Exprator

Comment: check the spelling with the upper ones, its broswer , change it to browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146088/discussion-between-wizard-and-exprator).

Answer (score 0):

```
<noscript>
Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.
</noscript>
```

That is going to be a challenge:
https://www.quora.com/Can-beautifulsoup-scrape-javascript-rendered-webpages

In my past I did a lot of work with writing spiders in Perl and javascript was always a challenge if the content we wanted was created by the javascript.  We would have to use some kind of 3rd party tool to read/render/output the javascript to an html file, then simply import that data for parsing.

The link above has a few tools that should do the trick. Good luck!